# Should I trust Imagick::getImageFormat()?

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, imagick

I need to know whether I can trust this code to get the image format:

```
$image = new Imagick($path);
$format = $image->getImageFormat();
```

Or should I still check extension, mime type, etc like usual?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can trust it much more than just checking the extension of the file (`pic.jpg` for example) with simple php string functions.

You can have an experiment. Rename a `.jpg` image file so that it becomes `.png`, for example. Use simple tools of the Windows "Rename". So it seems now that the image is a `.png` image.
But try `Imagick` in `cmd` with `-verbose` command, like this:

```
C:\>identify -verbose pic.png
Image: pic.png
  Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 482x362+0+0
  Resolution: 72x72
  ... many more here ...
```

And you will see that in reality  the image is `.jpg`. The same is with your `$image->getImageFormat();` somewhere in your program.

`Imagick` is powerful tool. Unfortunately there is much less information about its API in PHP than GD has.

Comment: Yes that's the problem, there is little to no information about Imagick in the php docs. Somewhere in there I read a comment that said 'getImageFormat' only shows the format you have set yourself. But I haven't set any format and it worked fine, so I don't know... I also know an extension is not enough, I used to check everything, and discard at the minor threat, eg: it doesn't matter if it seems to be a gif. If its extension is .sh or .php, I discard it, because there could be code masked as a gif.

Comment: That's getFormat that returns what you set, based on the documentation, getImageFormat is more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not comfortable with the `Imagick` class, you could always try the GD functions. For example

```
list (width, height, $type) = getimagesize($path);
```

The `$type` variable will be one of `IMAGETYPE_GIF`, `IMAGETYPE_JPEG`, `IMAGETYPE_PNG`, etc

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php and http://php.net/manual/en/image.constants.php

Comment: Yes that's good, but I didn't want to open the image many times. If I can do it with Imagick it's better, because I'm going to use it for other things anyway.